# Render a Partial, only for fist time, Best Practice

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

Hi I´ve 1 View with info and a conteiner to load 2 PartialViews,once at a time.

I can load the first one (Form with parameters for a query), by $.ajax() in a function, that I call in the $(document).ready.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#btnConsultarPadron').click(function () {
    Consultar();
});
CargarFormParametros();


function CargarFormParametros() {
$.ajax({
    url: '/apps/Controller/Action/CargarForm',
    data: {},
    success: function (result) {
        $("#contenedorGral").html(result);
    },
    error: function AjaxFailed(result) {
        alert('Error')
    },
});
```

But when I replace that one with the other Partial(query's result) with a click Fired ajax event, It seems that the $(document).ready is called again, and I got the first Partial.

Which is the best practice to do that?

Comment: Are you sure the page wasn't reloaded? When the page loads the dom ready will fire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove your scripts from **contenedorGral** div and write them out site of that div